# What are these constructions?

Tags: sentence-construction, construction

- When you **red painted** the car, you scratched it. *(When you painted the car red)*
- If I **hand make** something I sell twice the regular price. *(If I make something with my hands)*
- What if I **ice freeze** the milk, will it last longer? *(What if I make milk freese until it becomes ice)*

I know what they mean but what are they called?

There's also:

- They had to **baby sit** me all day while my parents where at work.

Comment: "When you red painted the car" does not sound at all correct to me.

Comment: Neither of these sentences are correct, so telling you what the construction is is pointless.

Comment: ... the third sentence isn't correct, either. Now, what's wrong with the second sentence **isn't** the bold part... it's the rest of the sentence... "If I handmake something, I **can** sell it at twice the regular price"... but "handmake" is a verb.

Comment: "Babysit" is also a verb. Can you please explain what you're trying to understand? Adding more examples doesn't really do much if you're unclear what you're going for.

Comment: I think SS is looking for compound verbs like **babysit** and **sandblast** and **hogtie** and **pistolwhip**  and **chickenfry**

Comment: When placing the noun before the verb, what are such constructions called?

Comment: You can't **generally** do this, though. It requires that the two words have been merged into an idiomatic compound verb... That's why "red painted" and "ice freeze" don't work.

Comment: A @Catija is saying, such constructions are often called "bad English."

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Chickenfry?

Comment: @Catija Okay what about placing a hyphen betweenn these words? Tromano pointed to yhe right thing. Those are compound verbs too.

Comment: *Can you chickenfry that steak, honeybun?*

Comment: You don't generally use them as verbs the way you are when you hyphenate... they're adjectives. "The red-painted barn was an iconic part of country life." etc.

Comment: "Hand-make" and "baby-sit" are well-established verbs. But there's no such verb as "red-paint" or "ice-freeze", so these must be seen as nonce-formations.